# Even selected, no windows content refresh, I have to change the windows size

Tags: linux-mint, window

Linux MATE 19.1, Nvidia graphics.
Not at all times, but even selected, no windows content refresh, I have to change the windows size.
Happens only in browsers window (Firefow, Chrome, Chromium).
By example, it is only when resizing that the previous active tab jump to the real active tab, a conversation tab show the new messages, tab refresh, ..

I was unable to see any parameters triggering this behaviour.

Comment: What exact model of video card do you have, and which driver (version of `xserver-xorg-video-nvidia`, if that's the right package name)? Sometimes these things are a bug of a specific video driver with a specific graphics chip. For Chrome, you can try fiddling with likely-looking settings in `chrome://flags/` as a temporary workaround until the bug is fixed.

Comment: I have a graphics GeForce 9600GT,  the installed nVidia driver is 340.107.
I will check the parameters.

Comment: I replace the graphics card by a more powerfull one  (GeForce GTX 970), and it seems that that solve the problem.